# How to search value by key from Map as well as Nested Map

Tags: groovy

I have a `Map` as below :-

```
def map = [
        a:"a",
        b:[f:"f", g:"g"],
        c:"c",
        d:"d",
        e:[h:"h", i:[j:"j"]],
    ]
```

Here I want to search value by given key. But problem is provided key is single unique key instead of nested key hierarchy as below :-

```
println map.a
println map.j
```

Here output as expected :-

```
a
null
```

As you can see, I can't get value for `j` key, I know because this key is not present in root `Map` but it is present in nested `Map`. If I do as below :-

```
println map.e.i.j
```

It gives me correct output but I don't know this hierarchy of keys.

Is there any way to get value from above `map` by passing exact key only??

**Note** :- All keys are always unique in the provided `Map`.

Comment: The easiest would be actually to dont nest maps, or they must nest?

Comment: @Joel key could be any where root map as well as nest map but all keys would be unique.

Comment: so cant you place j in the root?

Comment: @Joel Yeah,I know..but I don't know how to search value from this map with this key which could be anywhere. Thanks

Comment: It would be very hard then...

Comment: @Joel Let's see, may be someone has faced same issue, I also doing research for this task. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196454/groovy-find-a-key-in-a-map-and-return-its-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044614/finding-the-key-in-a-map-given-the-value. These links should help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a simple tree traversal:

```
def findDeep(Map m, String key) {
    if (m.containsKey(key)) return m[key]
    m.findResult { k, v -> v instanceof Map ? findDeep(v, key) : null }
}
```

Given your input map, the following test code:

```
('a'..'k').each { key ->
    println "${key}: ${findDeep(map, key)}"
}
```

Yields the following results:

```
a: a
b: [f:f, g:g]
c: c
d: d
e: [h:h, i:[j:j]]
f: f
g: g
h: h
i: [j:j]
j: j
k: null
```

Comment: If the person who marked this down would be so kind as to comment on the shortcomings, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm using similar method to get value (by `m.containsValue(value)` ). Appreciate for example.